# GAUSS-NEWTON algorithm to solve a non-linear system?

Tags: analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, regression

I need a parameter to use in Poisson. I want to calculate this parameter using the [Gauss-Newton algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm), starting from a nonlinear system. I want to point out that i am assuming that the distribution is Poisson with parameter  `$\mu$`

My goal is to use Poisson (**which is not relevant to this question**, because with this question i just want to get the only parameter of Gauss-Netwon to use in Poisson) to individually calculate the probabilities of a football club scoring `0 goals`, `1 goal`, `2 goals`, `3 goals`, `4 goals`, etc. etc. So I need to find a parameter using the Gauss-Newton algorithm.

In an experimental test, i tried to use the Arithmetic Mean in Poisson, then i use the parameter `1.6` to calculate the probability that a football team individually scores goals, 1 goal, 2 goals, 3 goals, 4 goals, etc. etc. The results are decent, but I would like to get something more precise. So I thought of using another parameter, which is what i would like to find with the `Gauss-Newton algorithm` and the nonlinear system.

The basic, initial idea, is to start from `List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]` which i organize in the non-linear system, building it with the goals [1, 2, 2, 1, 2] and the number of times the event occurs

**BASIC DATA:**

```
List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
Matches played: 5 
Standard Deviation: 0.55
```

**NON-LINEAR SYSTEM:**

If a football club, in the last 5 matches,scores [1, 2, 2, 1, 2], it means that:

- 0 goals, scored 0 times ( );
- 1 or less goals, scored 2 times (1, 1);
- 2 or less goals, scored 5 times (1, 2, 2, 1, 2);

therefore:

```
If the goals scored are <= 0 events, then i will have 0/5 = 0;
If the goals scored are <= 1 events, then i will have 2/5 = 0.4;
If the goals scored are <= 2 events, then i will have 5/5 = 1;

f(0) = 0/5 = 0;
f(1) = 2/5= 0.4;
f(2) = 5/5= 1;

System: {f(0) = F(0) } therefore 0/5= 0
        {f(1) = F(1) } therefore 2/5= 0.4
        {f(2) = F(2) } therefore 5/5= 1
```

In this case i have three equations in one unknown, but obviously the system must be set up with a number of equations ranging from `F(0)` to `F(max_goals_scored)`. This way I would have `max_goals_scored + 1 equations`.I should therefore start the solution starting from `max_goals_scored+1` equations and increase, for example up to a maximum of 5 goals:

```
F(0), F(1), F(2), F(3), F(4), F(5)
```

**GAUSS-NEWTON ALGORITHM:**

I'm having trouble using the Gauss-Newton algorithm, so i'm asking for help. I understand the theory, but i'm having trouble putting it into practice. Specifying that, what I'm looking for for the resolution and the final result is this:

**a)** I identify the `Jacobian matrix J`, which in general is composed of the partial derivatives with respect to all the parameters. In this case i only have one parameter and the matrix is actually a column vector;

**b)** I calculate the transpose of `J` multiplied by `J`, which in this case is a scalar (formally a number, which however in this case is a function of the unknown parameter);

**c)** algorithmically speaking it looks good: the inverse of `J^T*J` is still a scalar, so I have to divide by that number (which however will contain the `mu parameter`);

**d)** I write the `iterative method` according to the formula and a stopping criterion;

Naturally, these steps therefore, include functions and functional operators (the derivative). How can i use the Gauss-Network algorithm on the non-linear system and get the final result? Can you show me the various steps with my numerical data applied? (and not just with the formulas). Thank you all!!!

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me what system you are actually trying to solve? Can you write clearly the objective function you wish to minimize?

Comment: @giorgi nguyen I have updated the question, including more information and also an image. I'm not very knowledgeable about nonlinear systems, so I apologize if I can't give you more information. I hope that what I wrote in UPDATE is useful for you to understand what I would like to achieve

Comment: @giorginguyen I updated the question again. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment.

It is not entirely clear to me what you are asking, you seem to have all the information necessary. However the notation could be improved.

I am using $F_k(\mu) = e^{-\mu} \sum_{j=0}^k { \mu^j \over j!}$ and am assuming that $f_e(k)$ represents the corresponding experimental datum. It is straightforward to compute $F_k'(\mu)$.

I am guessing that you have a system of equations $r:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$,
$r_k(\mu) = F_k(\mu)-f_e(k)$, then you would like to solve $r(\mu) \approx 0$.

To apply at iteration of Gauss Newton at some iteration $e_n$ you linearise $r$ as in
$r(\mu_{n+1}) \approx r(\mu_n) + Dr(\mu_n) (\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n)$ and (attempt to) solve the system
$r(\mu_n) + Df(\mu_n) (\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n) = 0$ to compute $e_{n+1}$.

Using ordinary least squares, we have the update rule
$\mu_{n+1} = \mu_n - (Dr(\mu_n)^T Dr(\mu_n))^{-1} Dr(\mu_n)^T r(\mu_n)$.

In this case (assuming that I understand correctly) you have, $Dr(\mu) = \begin{bmatrix} F_0'(\mu) \\ F_1'(\mu) \\ F_2'(\mu) \end{bmatrix}$.

A readable explanation of Gauss Newton can be found [here](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/07-ls-reg.pdf), some standard improvements (Armijo step size, LevenbergMarquardt) can be found [here](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eaaa/Public/Teaching/ORF363_COS323/F14/ORF363_COS323_F14_Lec9.pdf).

**Another approach**:

The following plots the sum of errors squared vs. the Poisson $\mu$ parameter for the data [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]. There could easily be errors in my implementation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

goals = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
def f(k):
    """Observed data."""
    return len(list(filter(lambda j: j <= k, goals)))/len(goals)

def poisson_cdf(mu, k):
    """Poisson CDF."""
    return sum(mu**j/math.factorial(j) for j in range(0, k+1))*math.exp(-mu)

def lsq_error(mu, k_vals):
    """Sum of squares of errors."""
    return sum((poisson_cdf(mu, k)-f(k))**2 for k in k_vals)

# Find the error for values of k in k_vals.
k_vals = [0, 1, 2]
# Plot x range.
mu_vals = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
lsq_error_vals = np.array(list(lsq_error(mu, k_vals) for mu in mu_vals))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(mu_vals, lsq_error_vals)

ax.set(xlabel='mu', ylabel='lsq error',
       title='sum of errors squared vs. mu')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("error.png")
plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot from which we can visually see that there is a $\min$ around $1.6$.
[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149476/discussion-between-horiatiki-and-copper-hat).

Comment: @Horiatiki copper.hat attempted to help you.  It seems that their best efforts have not been to your liking, which is *fine*.  They have given you as much help as they are willing and/or able to do.  At this point, you need to stop pestering them, as I think they have made it clear that they no longer wish to engage with this question.